# Sometimes I end up as stars?

Tags: riddle

> Sometimes I end up as stars?
>
> Like or dislike by peoples,
>
> Yes, of course I'm reason of hurt and quarrel,
>
> Sites want to prevent me.
>
> I am Bitter sometimes funny.
>
> Singers use me sometimes.
>
> I think I am fashion of new generation.
>
> Who am I?

Comment: Poor grammar in "When I m" is intentional?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> You're profanity.

Why I m end up with stars?

> Profanity is frequently replaced with ****.

Like or dislike by peoples,

> Some people have a real objection, others enjoy it as emphasis.

Yes, of course I'm reason of hurt and quarrel,

> Certain types can instigate arguments, anger, and even hurt.

Sites want to prevent me.

> Many websites implement auto-filters to the **** above

I am Bitter sometimes funny.

> Depending on the context, profanity can either indicate bitterness or add humor.

Singers use me sometimes.

> At one point: "Parental Advisory: Explicit Lyrics" was a common thing, as singers used more and more profanity in their lyrics.

I think I am fashion of new generation.

> Profanity is more acceptable in younger generations.

Comment: This is first thing came to mind.....but didn't dare to put it as answer :)

Comment: This must be it!

Answer (score 5):

(Note to censors: this answer is correct and in the spirit of the question. Please do not edit it!)

The answer is

> fucking obvious.

*Sometimes I end up as stars?*

> Words like "shit" often end up as just **** when censored out.

*Like or dislike by peoples,*

> Some people like to say words like "crap", others disdain them.

*Yes, of course I'm reason of hurt and quarrel,*

> Such words can cause a lot of shit between people!

*Sites want to prevent me.*

> The Stack Exchange censors are going to piss all over me for writing this answer!

*I am Bitter sometimes funny.*

> Such words can be used when you're really damn bitter, but they can also be entertaining.

*Singers use me sometimes.*

> The Sex Pistols?

*I think I am fashion of new generation.*

> Youngsters these days, always fucking swearing...

*Who am I?*

> See [lorimer's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/15548/5373).

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> privacy

?

Why I m end up with stars?

> because the way to hide something written can be replacing it with ****

Like or dislike by peoples,

> most people like to have their privacy, but the business owners and politicians do not like the privacy of others

Yes, of course I'm reason of hurt and quarrel,

> privacy is a hot topic at the moment and reason for arguments and discussions

Sites want to prevent me.

> most of the web sites may violate your privacy or ask for registrations.

I am Bitter sometimes funny.

> showing private information for someone is bitter or shameful,yet sometimes very amusing for the audience (reddit anyone?)

Singers use me sometimes.

> because singers are stars and people tend to violate the privacy of famous people

I think I am fashion of new generation.

> so it is.. we kind of lost our privacy, now we want to get it back