# Alone In My Cave

Tags: riddle, rhyme

As always, I hope this isn't too easy, and that you enjoy the rhymes :)

> You often leave me, alone in my cave.
>   
>  When I peek out, I best not misbehave.
>
> If I go venture I can become quite ironic.
>   
>  But in certain ways, I have become iconic.
>
> I try to stay away from the cat.
>   
> But I am very strong, you may not know that!
>
> Some may think I have precious metal around,
>   
> I would show them!! If I wasn't so bound.
>
> You can go and try, to ask me a question.
>   
> But if I'm tied up, I can't seem to function.

What could I be?

Make sure to explain each line/couplet as they are relative.

---

*If you enjoyed this riddle, some of my other rhyming riddles can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brhyme%5D%20user%3A11244%20is%3Aquestion)*.

Comment: I can't stop thinking it might be a vacuum cleaner

Comment: @PirateSoul I can see how you might think that, but that isn't the answer :(

Comment: Because I'm Batman!

Comment: The Gimp from Pulp Fiction. I don't want to explain.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is it:

> The tongue

You often leave me, alone in my cave.

> In this case the mouth is the cave

When I peek out, I best not misbehave.

> Referring to sticking your tongue out mischievously

If I go venture I can become quite ironic.

> "Tongue-in-cheek"

But in certain ways, I have become iconic.

> Rolling Stones / Einstein's iconic tongue picture 
>  
>  Or could be a reference to the commonly used sticky-out-tongue emoticon?

I try to stay away from the cat.

> "Cat's got your tongue"

But I am very strong, you may not know that!

> I think I heard it was the strongest muscle in the body

Some may think I have precious metal around,

> A reference to someone being "Silver tongued"

I would show them!! If I wasn't so bound.

> Attached by the frenulum

You can go and try, to ask me a question.

> Because it can respond!

But if I'm tied up, I can't seem to function.

> Tongue-tied!

Comment: This is correct! Since this was answered about the same time as another answer, I will accept the one which is most voted for, and that appropriately answers all of the lines.

Comment: Lines 2,3,(possibly 4) and 7 can be 'improved' with better suited answer.

Comment: I think "peek out" is sticking your tongue out, not speaking.

Comment: I think "precious metal" refers to someone being "silver-tongued"

Comment: Oh, I've never heard silver-tongued! I was going to change it the fact that most precious metals can be found in the blood. Yours fits much better!

Comment: I think ironic goes best with -in-cheek

Comment: Hint: For Iconic, I was thinking more literal ;p

Answer (score 7):

> Tongue

You often leave me, alone in my cave. 
When I peek out, I best not misbehave.

> In the mouth. sticking out tongue for mischief

If I go venture I can become quite ironic. 
But in certain ways, I have become iconic.

> tongue-in-cheek and rolling stones tongue? not so sure about this part

I try to stay away from the cat. 
But I am very strong, you may not know that!

> Cat got your tongue. and tongue is the strongest muscle

Some may think I have precious metal around, 
I would show them!! If I wasn't so bound.

You can go and try, to ask me a question. 
But if I'm tied up, I can't seem to function.

> tongue tied

Comment: This is correct! Since this was answered about the same time as another answer, I will accept the one which is most voted for, and that appropriately answers all of the lines.

Answer (score 4):

An alternate and a bit adult (and hopefully humorous) answer. You have been warned:

> A penis

You often leave me, alone in my cave.
When I peek out, I best not misbehave.

> Often trapped in those represive pants, but always wanting to poke out. Don't go places you aren't supposed to. That leads to things...

If I go venture I can become quite ironic.
But in certain ways, I have become iconic.

> Definately the icon of the male portion of the species, but depending on characteristics (who has the hammer?), possibly ironic.

I try to stay away from the cat.
But I am very strong, you may not know that!

> Cats like to play with things that dangle. Be careful. And they can be very strong when, well, yeah....

Some may think I have precious metal around,
I would show them!! If I wasn't so bound.

> Certain piercings have become popular with gold, silver, platinum, etc. These could be shown off to the world (and sometimes are), but again, those repressive pants keep things bound.

You can go and try, to ask me a question.
But if I'm tied up, I can't seem to function.

> Some men talk to Little John, and ask him why he doesn't work. And if he is too constrained, then things cannot progress (whether in relieving oneself, or otherwise).

Comment: OMG... Guess I can't really criticise this, given [my own latest answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15544/sometimes-i-end-up-as-stars/15577#15577) ;-)

Comment: For some reason this was also the first answer which came to my mind. I think it was the "When I peek out, I best not misbehave" part that lead my mind to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:

Is it

> Wine

You often leave me, alone in my cave.

> Wine can be kept in caves

When I peek out, I best not misbehave.

> Wine (and alcohol) can make us misbehave

If I go venture I can become quite ironic.

> We drink wine to feel good but it can hurt us (which is ironic)

But in certain ways, I have become iconic.

> Wine is iconic for some people

I try to stay away from the cat.

> Not sure

But I am very strong, you may not know that!

> People tend to under estimate the percentage of alcohol in wine

Some may think I have precious metal around,

> Some wine get medals (gold, silver,...)

I would show them!! If I wasn't so bound.

> Not sure

You can go and try, to ask me a question.

> Some people are looking for solutions in alcohol (wine)

But if I'm tied up, I can't seem to function.

> If the cork is still here, you can't drink it